# Swift typealias error

Tags: swift, type-alias

I'm starting to learning Swift and I'm currently following some tutorials and I'm stuck here with this problem.

After I declare this:

```
typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String) -› Void;
```

I got this error:

> Tuple element cannot have two labels

I need this LoginHandler to have a message and retrieve void so I can use it in my login function to handle my Firebase errors.

```
typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String) -› Void;

class AuthProvider {
    private static let _instance = AuthProvider();

    static var Instance: AuthProvider {
        return _instance;
    }

    func login(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?){
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion:  {(user, error) in
            if error != nil {
            } else {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

So I have been trying different things but none of them have worked.

[image: full code with errors]

Comment: You need to create an `MCVE`: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Images of small snippets of code are not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a correct function type declaration:

```
typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String) -› Void
```

You are using the wrong "greater than" symbol (unicode hex 203A).

Your code should look like this:

```
typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String) -> Void
```

Notice that difference in the second character making up the "arrow operator" (unicode hex 003E).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm using a virtual machine and i wasn't aware of the typos. It solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add a space after ">"

```
typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String) -> Void
```

Comment: Thanks but that didn't helped, please check my new update.